# How to open Live server in specific Chrome Profile

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, web-development-server

**I have tried changing settings but I could not find setting that could open the live server in the another profile of chrome.** *If anyone have some idea how to do it please let me know*. BTW I have no problem using the default chrome profile or incognito setting provided in the drop drop list, I am just curious that is that possible if we can open live server in another chrome profile than the default one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what live server you have in mind, but you can probably use the command line for your system. For example, if you're using Windows and the Live Server extension for vsc, under the "**Advance Custom Browser Cmd Line**" option you can use "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome.exe --profile-directory=Profile 1**".